# How do I find Android SDKs on Mac when Studio can't?

Tags: android, macos, sdk

Apple's Catalina update wrecked at least two development environments on my computer, by deciding that they're security risks and dumping them into "previously relocated files."

Android Studio, which previously worked fine and has several SDKs installed, now prompts me to tell it where the SDK is on launch. I would think that they're under this directory structure somewhere, but so far I haven't found what to select as an SDK root. What is it looking for?

The SDKs are not installed under ~/Library on my system, by the way.

[image]

Comment: The /Developer/Android folder in your screenshot appears to be the Android SDK

Comment: WINNER! Thanks. So odd... this obviously isn't "the" SDK, but rather numerous ones. If you want to re-post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/Developer/Android` folder in your screenshot *is* the "Android SDK". Contained within the subfolders are the components of the different API levels.

The "SDK Manager" tool explains it quite well:

> Each Android SDK Platform package includes the Android platform and sources pertaining to an API level by default.

So, your Android SDK contains one or more "SDK Platforms", each corresponding to a different API level, as well as various other tools and libraries.

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't tell you what counts as an "Android SDK Platform package." In other words, how do you recognize it on disk, in cases like this where you have to manually navigate to it and select its root with a file browser.

Comment: You shouldn't have to find an individual package on disk, just the Android SDK (the root folder). The structure of the individual API levels (platform packages) within is irrelevant, and managed by the SDK Manager tool.

Comment: To clarify: That statement from the SDK Manager does not tell you what the name of the SDK root folder is, or provide a way to identify it by its contents.

Comment: In the SDK Manager, the very first control is an editable text field showing the location of the Android SDK that it is referring to. The name of the root folder is whatever you name it to be, it doesn't have to be "android-sdk" or whatever.

Comment: The SDK Manager couldn't show the location of the Android SDK that it was referring to, because it wasn't referring to one. That is the entire reason for this post: Android Studio had lost the reference to the SDK, so it was hounding me to provide the location manually. And I realize that the folder could have an arbitrary name, which is why I said "or provide a way to identify it by its contents."

Answer (score 0):

You can set your ANDROID_HOME environment variable to the path of the Android SDK (By default it is installed into /Users/{YOUR_USER}/Library/Android/sdk)
Optionally you can set the sdk.dir variable inside your local.properties file (inside your project folder)

Inside local.properties file:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/Rander/Library/Android/sdk
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does that answer my question?

Comment: Sorry, i think i misunderstood the question